# Can I save and load a heterogenous list of polymorphic types in MongoEngine?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I want to save and load a heterogenous list of polymorphic types in MongoEngine.
What I ideally want would look like:

```
from mongoengine import Document, EmbeddedDocument, IntField, StringField
class BaseEmbedded(EmbeddedDocument):
    meta = {'abstract': True}
class FooEmbedded(BaseEmbedded):
    an_int = IntField()
class BarEmbedded(BaseEmbedded):
    a_string = StringField()
class HasList(Document):
    heterogeneous_list = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(BaseEmbedded))
has_list = HasList()
has_list.heterogeneous_list = [FooEmbedded(an_int=3), BarEmbedded(a_string='bar')]
has_list.save()
HasList.objects(id=has_list.id)
```

The problem is that when saving an EmbeddedDocument, its specific polymorphic type is lost, so there's not enough data to reconstruct my original subclass:

```
[{"an_int":3}, {"a_string":"bar"}]
```

Unlike when saving a top-level Document, where the name of the specific class of the Document is the name of the collection in the DB.

I could make `BaseEmbedded` a `DynamicEmbeddedDocument`, add a 'type' `StringField` with appropriate values for each subtype, and reconstruct the list element objects based on the type field.

Is there a better solution I didn't think of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mapping JSON to classes is what Mongoengine does and is also supported for embedded documents.
You need to set allow_inheritance=True in the embedded document's meta.

Comment: [allow_inheritance](https://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/guide/defining-documents.html#document-inheritance)